# Transpose non-well formed XML document to an HTML Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I am working on a project that requires me to  parse an XML tree where the XML is not so great.  I need to define a UL structure from the XML but the issue is that all the nodes are the same name with different attributes. I am using jQuery ajax function to call this XML file and return it on success. Here is my conundrum:

```
>     <class name="Juice">
>       <class name="OJ">
>         <class name="Low Sugar" />
>         <class name="Some Pulp" />
>       </class>
>       <class name="Apple" />
>       <class name="Grape" />
>     </class>
```

As you can see the node names make it hard to transpose this to a uniformed list. I am trying to get this to recurse and look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Juice
        <ul>
            <li>OJ
                <ul>
                    <li>Low Sugar</li>
                    <li>Some Pulp</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Grape</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "nav.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        xmlParser(xml);
    }
});
```

my xmlParser function:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {

    $(xml).find("class class").each(function () {

        var cname = $(this).attr("name");

        if ($(this).children.length > 0) {

            $("#nav .categories").append("<li id='" + cname + "'><a href='#'>" + cname + "</a></li>");
            $(xml).find("[name='" + cname + "']").children().each(function () {
                var cname1 = $(this).attr("name");
                $("#" + cname).append("<ul></ul>");
                $("#" + cname + " ul").append("<li id='" + cname1 + "'><a href='#'>" + cname1 + "</a></li>");
            });

        } else {
            $("#nav .categories").append("<li id='" + cname + "'><a href='#'>" + cname + "</a></li>");
        }
    });

}
```

My HTML on the page where I want to append the unordered list:

```
<ul id="nav" class="categories"></ul>
```

This ends up duplicating some code and is not recursive, I would like to get something where I can recall the parseXml function and pass some argument where the elements are not duplicated in the tree. I would rather trash this function and start over with something cleaner and neater.

Are there any jQuery plugins that do this already.  I have checked this site and Google but nothing I am looking for works with this bad XML. All others I found use a well formed XML structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can see your XML *is* well-formed. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Maybe I stated it wrong, I meant a non typical XML structure where all the nodes are named the same or maybe there is another term for it?

Comment: Eh? The xml he posted isn't well formed. Those two close tags shouldn't be there. Things is, if it isn't well formed it's not xml, it's badly written markup. Or may be not just looking at it again... My bad

Comment: Not brill, but clearer

Comment: Thats what I thought, I expected all nodes <class> to have an end tag </class>  not use <class /> right?  Anyhow, this comes through and I can iterate over the nodes but seems it can't tell what is a sibling or a child.  Is there a way to muscle this markup into a UL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var isIE = (window.attachEvent);


var txt = "<class name=\"Juice\"><class name=\"OJ\"><class name=\"Low Sugar\" /><class name=\"Some Pulp\" /></class><class name=\"Apple\" /><class name=\"Grape\" /></class>";
var doc = NewXmlDoc(txt);
var output = "<ul>";
WalkTree(doc.documentElement);
output+="</ul>";
alert( output );

function WalkTree(node)
{
    output += "<li>"+node.getAttribute("name");
    if (node.childNodes.length > 0)
    {
        output += "<ul>";
        for (var inx = 0; inx < node.childNodes.length; inx++)
        {
            var childNode = node.childNodes[inx];
            WalkTree(childNode);
        }
        output += "</ul>";
    }
    output += "</li>";
}


function NewXmlDoc(sXml) 
{
  var xmlDoc;
  if (isIE)
  {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(sXml);
    if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0)
        return null;
  }
  else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(sXml, "text/xml");

  return xmlDoc;
}

/* Result is...
<ul>
  <li>Juice
      <ul>
        <li>OJ
            <ul>
              <li>Low Sugar</li>
              <li>Some Pulp</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Grape</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
 */

</script>
```

Comment: Worked nicely!  Thank you for helping me out!